# CakePHP - basic login functionality not working

Tags: cakephp, authentication

I am wrestling with CakePHP trying to create a basic login functionality. So far CakePHP is winning. I followed the basic Blog tutorial and based on that I am try to create a similair login thingy.

The only difference I have is that I not using an Users model, but a custom Employers model and I use email/password instead of username/password.

Yet all I get is "Your username or password was incorrect."

**AppController.php**

```
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');

class AppController extends Controller {

    public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect' => array(
                'controller' => 'schedules',
                'action' => 'index'
            ),
            'logoutRedirect' => array(
                'controller' => 'employers',
                'action' => 'login',
                'home'
            ),
            'authenticate' => array(
                'Form' => array(
                    'fields' => array(
                        'username' => 'email',
                        'password' => 'password'
                    ),
                    'userModel' => 'Employer',
                    'passwordHasher' => 'Blowfish'
                )
            )   
        )
    );
}
```

**EmployersController.php**

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
class EmployersController extends AppController {

public $helpers = array('Form');

public function beforeFilter()
{
    parent::beforeFilter();

    $this->Auth->allow('login');
}

public function login()
{
    $layout = 'login';
    $this->layout = $layout;

    if($this->request->is('post'))
    {
        debug($this->Auth->login());
        if($this->Auth->login())
        {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        }
        else
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Your username or password was incorrect.');
        }

        debug($this->request->data['Employers']['password']);
    }
}
}
```

**Login.ctp**

```
<div id="login-container">
<h1>Login</h1>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->create('Employers');
    echo $this->Form->input('email', array('label' => false, 'placeholder' => 'Email'));
    echo $this->Form->input('password', array('label' => false, 'placeholder' => 'Password'));
    echo $this->Form->submit();
    echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

When I debug $this->request->data, the data is structered like data["Employers"]['email'] & data["Employers"]['password']. This is propably not right, since my model is called Employer.

Is this correct and does the login functionality break on this and if so, how can I fix that?
Or is there something else I am overlooking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your login.ctp,

It should be `echo $this->Form->create('Employer');` not with s, so remove s and try it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hm, that seemed to work indeed. I thought I had to use the controller name, not the model one. My bad, thanks